# Operand type clash: date is incompatible with text

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, vb.net

I'm trying to create a questionnaire that writes to the database. Everything is set up but I just keep getting "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with text". I have another webform which allows the user to only insert times and dates and the datatypes match the same within this data form (i.e. time(7) and date) so I'm just  bit confused as to why it's not writing as I'm entering the correct data below is the entire code for the form:

```
    Dim EventID As Integer
    Dim Con As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim cmdstring As String = "SELECT EventID FROM [Event Table] WHERE EventName = @EventName"
    Con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\YellowDoor.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, Con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EventName", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue

    Con.Open()
    EventID = (cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    Con.Close()

    Dim recordsAffected As String
    Dim cmdstring2 As String = "INSERT [Question Table](EventID, DateOfMeeting, BrideName, BrideNumber, GroomName, GroomNumber, InvoiceAddress, BGAddress, EmailAddress, DateOfWedding, WeddingLocation, WeddingReception, MarqueeCompany, NumberOfGuests, WeddingTime, TravelToReception, ReceptionTime, LineUp, Speeches, SpeechesT, Beverages, SpeechTime, GlassHire, Grace, GraceName, CutCake, CakeDetails, Cake, MirrorPlatter, Sword, FoodTime, TablePlan, Easel,LinenNapkins, TableNumbers, Tables, HeatingAndLighting, Skip, CoatRail, Toilets, ChaffingDishes, GardenFurniture, MenuPrinting, PASystem, BoneChina, Virtu, TallStem, Candelabras, Flowers, Red, White, Still, Sparkling, GlassHireMeal, Corkage, EveningGuests, EveningTime, Cheese, Finger, Rolls, Other, EveningFoodT) Values(@EventID, @DateOfMeeting, @BrideName, @BrideNumber, @GroomName, @GroomNumber, @InvoiceAddress, @BGAddress, @EmailAddress, @DateOfWedding, @WeddingLocation, @WeddingReception, @MarqueeCompany, @NumberOfGuests, @WeddingTime, @TravelToReception, @ReceptionTime, @LineUp, @Speeches, @SpeechesT, @Beverages, @SpeechTime, @GlassHire, @Grace, @GraceName, @CutCake, @CakeDetails, @Cake, @MirrorPlatter, @Sword, @FoodTime, @TablePlan, @Easel, @LinenNapkins, @TableNumbers, @Tables, @HeatingAndLighting, @Skip, @CoatRail, @Toilets, @ChaffingDishes, @GardenFurniture, @MenuPrinting, @PASystem, @BoneChina, @Virtu, @TallStem, @Candelabras, @Flowers, @Red, @White, @Still, @Sparkling, @GlassHireMeal, @Corkage, @EveningGuests, @EveningTime, @Cheese, @Finger, @Rolls, @Other, @EveningFoodT)"
    Con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\YellowDoor.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring2, Con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EventID", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = EventID
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfMeeting", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtMeetingDate.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BrideName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtBride.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BrideNumber", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = txtBrideN.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GroomName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtGroom.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GroomNumber", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = txtGroomN.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceAddress", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtInvoice.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BGAddress", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtBAddress.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtEmail.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfWedding", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtDate.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@WeddingLocation", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtLocationS.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@WeddingReception", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtLocationR.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MarqueeCompany", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtMarquee.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NumberOfGuests", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtNumberOG.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@WeddingTime", SqlDbType.Time).Value = txtWeddingService.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TravelToReception", SqlDbType.Time).Value = txtTravelRecep.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReceptionTime", SqlDbType.Time).Value = txtReceptionTime.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LineUp", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = IIf(RadYes.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Speeches", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = IIf(RadYes0.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SpeechesT", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = IIf(RadBefore.Checked, "Before", "After")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Beverages", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtBeverage.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SpeechTime", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtToastT.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GlassHire", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = IIf(RadYes1.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Grace", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = IIf(RadYes2.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GraceName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtGrace.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CutCake", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadCakeYes.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CakeDetails", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtCakeDetails.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cake", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYes3.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MirrorPlatter", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYes4.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sword", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYes5.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FoodTime", SqlDbType.Time).Value = txtFoodTime.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TablePlan", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesTbl.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Easel", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesEasel.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LinenNapkins", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesLinen.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TableNumbers", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesTable.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tables", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesTC.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@HeatingAndLighting", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesHeat.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Skip", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesSkip.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CoatRail", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesCoat.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Toilets", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesToilet.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ChaffingDishes", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesChaf.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GardenFurniture", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesGarden.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MenuPrinting", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesMenu.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PASystem", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesPA.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BoneChina", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadBYes.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Virtu", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadVYes.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TallStem", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadGYes.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Candelabras", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadCanYes.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Flowers", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadFlowerYes.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Red", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadRedYes.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@White", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadWhiteYes.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Still", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadStillYes.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sparkling", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadSparkYes.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GlassHireMeal", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesGlass.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Corkage", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesCork.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EveningGuests", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadYesEvening.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EveningTime", SqlDbType.Time).Value = txtArrival.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cheese", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadCheeseYes.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Finger", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadFingerYes.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rolls", SqlDbType.Text).Value = IIf(RadCiabattaYes.Checked, "Yes", "No")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Other", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtEveningFS.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EveningFoodT", SqlDbType.Time).Value = txtEveningFood.Text
    Con.Open()

    recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    Con.Close()
```

Comment: you can do a datetime.tryparse to see if the text is a date and then pass the out parameter into the stored proc.

Comment: i dont understand where do I put the tryparse in the line??
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfWedding", SqlDbType.Date).Value = txtDate.Text

Comment: Can you use a datetime picker for this instead of a textbox? That would eliminate the hoops of trying to validate that the text is a valid datetime value.

Comment: You should send SqlDbType.Date parameter as a DateTime not a String. Same for the Time.

Comment: The next question is do you really have that many columns defined as text? Or are they actually varchar which will allow for implicit casting. Since you have a couple of parameters defined as varchar I suspect you are using the text datatype. This has been deprecated since 2005 and is a serious pita to work with.

Comment: And when using (n)varchar and (n)char you need to define the size of the parameter or it will use the default size which can lead to truncation.

Comment: You aren't replacing the `@variable` codes properly in your `cmdstring2 `. If you breakpoint on `recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` you can see that `cmd.CommandText` is ready to output exactly what the string was set to at the top, with all the `@` symbols and everything. So for example, `DateOfWedding` is trying to be inserted as `@DateOfWedding` which is obviously not a valid date. This isn't the way I normally set up my sql scripts so maybe someone with more experience in this can help you do it the way you want.

Comment: No I have a column for each one which has a data type of text, time or date

Comment: Yes, you have a column for each but they aren't being set properly. Test it yourself. Put a breakpoint on the `recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` line and check the value of `cmd.CommandText`. It doesn't have the correct values. Personally I **always** use stored procedures these days since I have been hit more than once in the past by sql injection attacks. Therefore I do not know the best way for you to solve your issue building an inline sql command but at least you know where your problem is now.

Comment: but the thing is I have several webforms within this site set up the exact same way with the storing of procedures so I'm just confused as to why this particular one won't

Comment: I could be wrong, but I copied your code and tested it myself and that is what I see. Again, maybe I don't understand fully how those `@` variables are being replaced in the `cmd.CommandText` as I was going to tell you to run that command in a query window to see if you can fix it there but I realized it wasn't outputting correctly. Put a breakpoint on one of your working procedures and check the value of `cmd.CommandText`. Does it also show up with the `@` characters instead of the real values? If so then I'm out to lunch, but then I'm not sure how you can test your sql in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dim rDate as DateTime
if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text, out rDate)) then
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfWedding", SqlDbType.Date).Value = rDate
else
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfWedding", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value
```

you can check to see whether the string in the textbox is valid and then put the parsed date into the parameter, otherwise pass null (or some default) into the parameter.